# react native хуки: изменить состояние через "внука" и передать его ребёнку для повторного рендера

Tags: react-native, react-hook

Помогите со следующей задачей, пожалуйста:
есть родительский элемент, в котором рендерится некий список (дочерний элемент), зависящий от состояния родителя. В этом списке есть дочерние элементы ("внуки" родительского): стрелки, листающие вправо-влево, и изменяющие состояние родителя. В классовом подходе всё работает (упрощаю код для удобочитаемости):

```
//родительский элемент
export default class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { page: 5 };
        this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    }
    nextPage() {
            let currentPage = this.state.page;
            this.setState({ page: currentPage +1});
        }
    render() {
        return (
                 <List 
                     onPageUp={this.nextPage}
                     statePage={this.state.page}
                 />
               );
        }
    }

//дочерний элемент
export default class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

render() {
        const thisPage = this.props.statePage;
        /*тут расчёты, зависящие  от thisPage*/
        return (
            <View>
               <ArrowRight onPageUp={this.props.onPageUp} />
               <SomeView />
            </View>
          );
      }
}


//правая стрелка - дочерний элемент дочернего элемента
export default class ArrowRight extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.props.onPageUp()}
                >                    
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь переписать на хуках - состояние родителя изменяется, но повторного рендера не происходит. Только после принудительного сохранения: сохранили код - нажали стрелку - пересохранили - новый рендер.

```
//родительский элемент
export default function Container() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(5);
    
    const nextPage = () => {
        let currentPage = page;
        setPage(currentDate + 1);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <List
                statePage={page}
                nextPage={nextPage}                
            />    
       </View>
    );
}

//дочерний элемент
export default function List (props) {
     
    const thisPage = props.statePage;
    /*тут расчёты, зависящие  от thisPage*/
    return (
        <View>
           <ArrowRight nextPage={props.nextPage} />
           <SomeView />
        </View>
}

//правая стрелка - дочерний элемент дочернего элемента
export default function ArrowRight(props) {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => props.nextPage()}
                >          
                </TouchableOpacity>         
            </View>
        )
}
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Функция внутри useCallback будет изменяться при любом изменении page (соответсвенно возвращать другое значение)

```
const nextPage = React.useCallback(() => {
   let currentPage = page;
   setPage(currentDate + 1);
}, [page]);
```

Доп. правки -

1.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.nextPage}>          
</TouchableOpacity>
```

2. Все `props` заменить на `{nextPage}` (и так далее) - я считаю так удобнее и понятнее

Comment: Александр, спасибо за уделенное время, но боюсь, не помогло.  Визуально поведение никак не изменилось.